# SortedCollection that ignores case in strings

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

By default, a `SortedCollection` is case sensitive (which seems surprising to me given how Strings are mostly used today), e.g.,

```
list := #('z' 'c' 'C' 'A' 'a').
slist := list asSortedCollection. "a SortedCollection('A' 'C' 'a' 'c' 'z')"
```

With Spotter, I found `caseInsensitiveLessOrEqual:` but wasn't sure how to use it with a `SortedCollection`. How can I easily get a sorted collection that ignores case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`asSortedCollection:` takes a sort block, too:

```
list := #('z' 'c' 'C' 'A' 'a').
slist := list asSortedCollection: 
    [ :a :b | a caseInsensitiveLessOrEqual: b ]. "a SortedCollection('a' 'A' 'C' 'c' 'z')"
```

**Edit** Here's a solution to get a consistent order (this is ugly, I got it from diving into `caseInsensitiveLessOrEqual:`)

```
caseInsensitiveCompare := [ :a :b | | result | 
    result := a compare: b caseSensitive: false.
    "equal ignoring case" 
    result = 2 ifTrue: [ a compare: b caseSensitive: true ].
    "less than, so return true (else return false since result=2)" 
    result = 1  ].

slist := list asSortedCollection: caseInsensitiveCompare. 
"a SortedCollection('A' 'a' 'C' 'c' 'z')"
```

Comment: you can accept your answer too.  It is better for others to know that you have found the solution.

Comment: @tukan I must wait for some time before selecting the correct solution. Perhaps you have a better one?

Comment: When I tought about it I was thinking exactly along your lines - `#asSortedCollection:` takes in a block where you define the condition.  Your solution is I think the most natural one.  (You can always do multiple ways but I prefer clean and simple solution)

Comment: Your solution does have the problem that it's not consistent about whether uppercase comes before lowercase or not: 'a', 'A', but 'C', 'c'.

Comment: I suggest that you accept your own solution as @tukan proposed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding the answer to address [@Amos M. Carpenter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/983430/amos-m-carpenter) comment - the sorting stability.  Your second code is unnecessarily complex.  What you could do is add one `asSortedCollection` to the `list` (which would sort the strings based alphabet position and "capitalness" and you would get consistent solution:

```
list := #('z' 'c' 'C' 'A' 'a') asSortedCollection.
slist := list asSortedCollection: 
    [ :a :b | a caseInsensitiveLessOrEqual: b ]. "SortedCollection('a' 'A' 'c' 'C' 'z')"

list := #('z' 'C' 'c' 'A' 'a') asSortedCollection.
slist := list asSortedCollection: 
    [ :a :b | a caseInsensitiveLessOrEqual: b ]."SortedCollection('a' 'A' 'c' 'C' 'z')"
```